# Como exibir os últimos 30 dias de uma consulta

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados, query

Estou tentando algumas alternativas para mostrar só os registros dos últimos 30 dias, mas não consegui fazer a coisa funcionar, a consulta que tenho está assim:

```
SELECT comunidade.descricao AS nomeunidade
      ,comcargo.descricao AS nomecargo
      ,comcolaborador.nome
      ,date_format(comcolaborador.dtadmissao,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dataadm
      ,comcolaborador.foto
      ,comcolaborador.idcargo
      ,comcolaborador.idunidade
      ,comcolaborador.login

  FROM comunidade
 INNER JOIN comcolaborador
    ON comunidade.idunidade = comcolaborador.idunidade
 INNER JOIN comcargo
    ON comcolaborador.idcargo = comcargo.idcargo

 WHERE comcolaborador.ativo = 1
   AND comcolaborador.dtadmissao >= '2016-08-01'
   AND comunidade.ativo = 1
   AND comcargo.ativo = 1
 ORDER BY comcolaborador.dtadmissao DESC
```

E o que tentei foi isso, seguindo algumas dicas e sugestões:

```
 WHERE data >= dateadd(minute,-30,getdate())
```

Comment: Só pra constar: `getdate()`, se não me falha a memória, não existe no MySQL. Ela funciona só no SQL Server.

Comment: Assim como [Sorack](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/59479/sorack) comentou, o equivalente de `getdate` no `MySQL`, é: [`curdate`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_curdate) ou [`now`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_now)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Opção 1**

Para decrementar uma data use [`DATE_SUB`](http://www.w3schools.com/Sql/func_date_sub.asp)

> DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL expr type)

No seu caso:

```
data >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 MINUTE)
```

**Opção 2**

Outro método descrito [nesta resposta do Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2041619/3388148) é o seguinte:

```
...
WHERE data BETWEEN NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY AND NOW()
...
```

**Observação:** A função [`GETDATE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/ms188383.aspx) é exclusiva (considerando os bancos de dados mais difundidos) do Transact-SQL (Implementação utilizada pelo SQL Server). Nos demais bancos temos outras funções com funcionamento similar, listadas abaixo:

- *MySQL:* NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_DATE, CURTIME;
- *Firebird:* CURRENT_DATE;
- *Oracle:* SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL;
- *PostgreSQL:* NOW, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;

Comment: Obrigado @Sorack, ajudou muito, valeu.

Answer (score 3):

Acredito que isto possa ajudar :

```
>=  CONVERT(CHAR(10), GETDATE()-30, 101)
```

O GETDATE()-30, trará os últimos trinta dias para a consulta, e usamos o convert para que a data saia no seguinte formato : 02/06/2017 (que é o formato 101). 
Caso queira em outros formatos sugiro ir testando 102,103,104 e assim por diante.

```
select CONVERT (varchar(20), getdate(), 101) --vá trocando os valores do 101 para ver qual melhor de atende, mas acredito que seja 101.
```